# Full width div background color inside a fluid grid layout

Tags: css, html, background, grid, fluid-layout

I am trying to create a div that is inside a fluid grid layout that has a background color that stretches across the entire width of the page but still holds content, like the dark blue and light blue sections of https://unroll.me/

Comment: This question is much too vague, and is covered at great length in other questions and basic search results.  However, you might want to start here http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/01/12/guidelines-for-responsive-web-design/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will need to create a div for the blue background. Then you will need to create a div inside of the blue background div to hold your content.

```html
<div id="blueBackground">

    <div id="contentDiv">

      <!-- your content here -->

    </div>

</div>
```

Next you will style the div's with CSS

```css
#blueBackground {
    background:#hexcolor;
    width:100%;
    padding: 40px 15px; /* first number sets vertical padding - second sets horizontal */
}

#contentDiv {
   width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: This worked! I just put div "blueBackground" outside the grid container and it did exactly what I wanted. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

```
#mydiv {
    width: 100%;
    background: blue;
}
```